# Let $G$ be finite s.t. there exists an epimorphism $\varphi: G\to\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_3$. Show $G$ has no cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group such that there exists an epimorphism $\varphi: G \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. Show that $G$ has no cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup.

**Attempt:** If I can prove that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ has no cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup then the result would follow immediately from the fact that the epimorphic image of a Sylow $p$-subgroup is a Sylow $p$-subgroup. The problem with this approach is (this was an exam problem) that it is a bit tedious (both the proof of the fact about the epimorphic image of Sylow subgroups as well as finding the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$). Is there an easier, perhaps more direct approach?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your attempt: It is not difficult to say what the $2$-Sylow subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ really is!

Comment: To add to @DietrichBurde, it has a unique order $4$ subgroup.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It should be $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. I got this by saying that since it is abelian it is the direct product of it's Sylow subgroups and by counting elements of order 3 we can say that it has a unique Sylow 3 subgroup which is $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Is this correct?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis it is enough to observe that $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ has order $4$. Uniqueness follows since it is normal.

Comment: @KentaS I don't see why it has to be unique?

Comment: It is known that Sylow $p$-subgroups have to be conjugate to each other. In particular, when they are normal, they are unique. Note that *all* subgroups of abelian groups are normal.

Comment: @KentaS Ohh I totally forgot about that! Thanks. I suppose there isn't a way to avoid the other part about the epimorphic image though.